# convert a string in upper case in vi

Tags: regex, vi

I want to upper case words in vi (this is a verilog syntax file where I want to change the connectivity).

For example:

`.STRING0(string1) .String2(string3)`,

I want to upper case one whole string and just first letter of second string 
something like

```
.STRING0(STRING1) .String2(String3),
```

My search pattern is:

```
%s/\.\(.*\)(\(.*\)) \.\(.*\)(\(.*\))/
```

and I need a replace pattern like

```
.\1(\2) .\3(\4)/
```

where buffer `\2` is completely upper-cased and contents of buffer `\4` is titled-cased. How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `\U` and `\u` substitution modifiers:

```
.\1(\U\2\E) .\3(\u\4)/
```

From the Vim help:

> ```
> `\u`      next character made uppercase
> `\U`      following characters made uppercase, until `\E`
> `\E`      end of \u, \U, \l and \L
> ```

Note that the above substitution will use title case for the `\4` match as long as it only contains one word, i.e., the substitution only converts the first character in the `\4` match.